# Having trouble getting access to a website's HTML using retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I am trying to get access to the HTML of this website: https://driverpracticaltest.dvsa.gov.uk/login . However whenever I try to get access to it using retrofit, the website keeps on redirecting, after 21 redirects it sends an error message: java.net.ProtocolException: Too many follow-up requests. Is this because of website security and is no way for me to get access to it's HTML? Any help would be appreciated.